# PostgreSQL performance worse when adding CPUs

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3

I ran into a strange behaviour when benchmarking PostgreSQL. The setup is like this:

- Virtual box VM, with 3 GB of RAM. The host has 16GB of RAM and 4 CPUs.
- Ubuntu 14.04, standard PostgreSQL 9.3 installation with the default configuration
- a single database with a single table having ~4k rows

I wrote a program that runs 10k simple selects (`select * from table_name where id = 1`) and times how long it takes to run them all.

When I assign a single CPU to the VM, it takes ~2.5 seconds to execute the queries.

With 2 CPUs, it takes more than 4 seconds.

With 3 CPUs, it takes more than 7 seconds.

With 2 (or 3) CPUs, if I also run at the same time another program which uses 100% CPU (but doesn't use the database), performance improves.

What's going on here?

Comment: How many concurrent connections are you using? Just one? I'm wondering if VBox is emulating an NUMA system. All in all, sounds likely to be a VBox problem more than a Pg issue.

Comment: I used only a single connection. I could also reproduce the behaviour where running a program that uses one CPU at 100% improves performance outside of virtualbox.

Comment: Or is PG bouncing over all the CPUs killing the various low-level caches? Does this link help? http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/assign-process-cpu-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Can you reproduce the same with current pg 9.4 (or even 9.5)?

Answer (score 1):

I often notice that PostgreSQL benchmarks run faster once more than half the CPUs are busy.  I think that what happens is Linux tries to keep the client and the server on different CPUs, which slows down the intense back-and-forth between them (which is the main thing your benchmark is benchmarking).  Once Linux is forced to run them on the same CPU, it gets faster.

Although I haven't seen the effect to be nearly as large as you report here.

Comment: That makes no sense. You want to leave the same process on the same processor if you can to cut down on cache reloads.

Comment: @gaius But they aren't the same process. There is a pgbench process (or thread) and a postgres process.  They talk to each other extensively.  They are different processes, and are the children of different processes.